# Compute the similarity of two graphs of different sizes

Tags: machine-learning, graph

I have two graphs *G* and *G'* (of different sizes) and I want to check how similar they are. I have read that the Wasserstein distance is used in this case.

How can I use it?

In scipy there is the function:

```
 scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance(u_values, v_values, u_weights=None, v_weights=None)
```

How can I pass *G* and *G'* as `u_values` and `v_values`?

**EDIT**:

I got the idea from this paper: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0228728&type=printable

Where they write:

> Inspired by the rich connections between graph theory and geometry, one can define a notion of distance between any two graphs by extending the notion of distance between metric spaces [58]. The construction proceeds as follows: each graph is represented as a metric space, wherein the metric is simply the shortest distance on the graph. Two graphs are equivalent if there exists an isomorphism between the graph represented as metric spaces. Finally, one can define a distance between two graphs G1 and G2 (or rather between the two classes of graph isometric to G1 and G2 respectively) by considering standard notions of distances between isometry classes of metric spaces [59]. Examples of such distances include the Gromov-Hausdorff distance [59], the Kantorovich-Rubinstein distance and the Wasserstein distance [60], which both require that the metric spaces be equipped with probability measures.

It is not clear to me though how to do this.

Comment: it's not immediately clear to me how to encode graphs as a probability distribution (maybe the edges as an adjacency matrix with probability 1). Can you maybe find the link where you've read that?

Comment: This question may be better suited to https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Additionally, it would be helpful if you would provide a clear example with example data, what you have tried so far, and expected output. Wasserstein Distance is useful in comparing distributions (like a histogram of colors from a pair of photographs), but might be less useful for comparing a graph of the sales curve of a part (which might be better served with something like dynamic time warping). And those are both different than comparing a mathematical graph which isn't a diagram/plot at all.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I have edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamSampson I have N graphs of different sizes and I would like to find a way of checking how similar/different they are, so that I am able to group them in C different clusters. I am reading the literature to understand how to do it from a practical point of view. Any pointer to where to start is very welcome :)